# Pass list from cshtml view to jquery function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im trying to pass List that is generated from the following function;

```
public List<long> GetIDs()
{
    var ids = new List<long>();
    foreach(var s in student)
    {
        ids.Add(s.ID);
    }
    return ids;
}
```

and passing the list through the razor view and access the list in the jquery.

Following is the CSHTML code :

```html
<a href="#" class="color-blue" data-studentids = "@schoolLicense.GetIDs()" onclick="sendWelcomeEmail(this)">
```

and this is the jquery code where I want to access the list and do actions from the ids I get ;

```
function sendWelcomeEmail(elem) {
    $.each($(elem).attr("data-studentids"), function (index, value) {
        alert(index + ": " + value);
    });
}
```

But I'm not getting the Ids from the list instead of that I'm getting error as

> TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
>   var length = !!obj && "length" in obj && obj.length,

Can anyone please let me know where Im going wrong?

Comment: Try checking how the html is rendered. I have a feeling that you can't invoke complicated functions inline like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because by outputting the `List<string>` returned from your `GetIDs` method you're just coercing it to a string. Therefore your output is:

```
<a href="#" data-studentids="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64]" ...
```

To fix this you can `Join()` the data together and then `split()` it back in to an array in your JS. Try this:

```js
public List<long> GetIDs()
{
    return student.Select(s => s.ID).ToList();
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="color-blue" data-studentids="@String.Join(",", schoolLicense.GetIDs())">
```

```js
$('.colour-blue').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).data('studentids').split(',').forEach(v, i) {
        console.log(i + ": " + v);
    });
});
```

Note the simplified use of LINQ in the `GetIDs` method, and the use of the unobtrusive event handler in the JS.

You can amend the `.colour-blue` selector in the jQuery object to better match your needs. I simply used it in this example as it was the only relevant attribute on the element.

Comment: **Thanks a ton** for pointing out the problem. It solved my issue.